# Find and remove all photos below a certain size threshhold

Tags: photos, data-recovery

So, I had a relative's hard drive collapse, and I've used [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to look for the most obvious files to retain (fortunately they only had pictures on the computer, everything else was cloud-synced, such as email) so I now have a parent-folder with 208 subfolders of all the PNG and JPG files from the old drive. Obviously a lot will be either "OS and Application images" (toolbars, sample images, thumbnails, system caches) and some will be "family photos".

If I can find some way to find all below a certain size (preferably say 300px wide) then sorting the rest *should* <sup>*</sup> be easy.

How can I use iPhoto or Spotlight or *something* to do this automatically? I'm also open to scripts using easily installed (brew perhaps?) libraries, if a script of some sort can be pointed to.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>famous last words</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the terminal to do this. The following command should work:

```
find /path/to/the/folder \
  -name "*.jpg" \
  -exec bash -c "sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth {} | grep -E ' [12]?[0-9]{0,2}$' >/dev/null" \;\
  -print
```

That command will find all JPEG files under `/path/to/the/folder` which have a width or a height of between 1 and 299 pixels.

Replace `/path/to/the/folder` with the actual path to your folder.

You can change `"*.jpg"` to `"*.gif"` to find GIF files instead.

You can change `[12]?[0-9]{0,2}` to change the size of the pictures you wish to locate. For example, to find pictures smaller than 500 pixels, use `[1234]?[0-9]{0,2}`

If you want to review which pictures this command finds, use:

```
find /path/to/the/folder \
  -name "*.jpg" \
  -exec bash -c "sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth {} | grep -E ' [12]?[0-9]{0,2}$' >/dev/null" \; \
  -exec mv {} /path/to/some/other/folder \;
```

Replace `path/to/some/other/folder` with the folder you want the files moved to, and that command will move the files it finds there.

---

The way this works is as follows:

The `sips` command is the *scriptable image processing system*. The terminal command `sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth some.jpg` will print out the width and height of the JPEG file.

The `find` command, as one might expect, finds files. `-exec` passed to find tells `find` to execute the specified command and only return files for which the command returns a successful result.

The command `bash -c "sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth {} | grep -E ' [12]?[0-9]{0,2}$'` invokes a shell, runs `sips` to get the image size, and then runs `grep`, which searches text, asking `grep` to search for either a `1` or a `2` followed by between zero and two digits (`0` through `9`). This is a *regular expression*, and it matches the numbers (strings) `1` through `299`

Answer (score 1):

In [Aperture](http://www.apple.com/aperture/) you can do this. And More!

## Step 1

1. Import all files into Aperture.
2. Use list view.
3. Click on an image size criteria to sort by that criteria. Note `pixel dimension` is probably the best method to use.
4. Select all files below your minimum size.
5. Delete

## Now for step 2 assuming these are family photos.

1. Turn on face recognition in Aperture, assign names to all
   recognizable faces.
2. Wait until library has been processed.This may take a while
   depending on number of files.
3. Now you can sort by face. (perhaps create a smart album for each
   face)
4. Select all photos containing a particular face.
5. Batch change metadata (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> +
   <kbd>b</kbd>), add a suitable keyword for each face.

Now you can export your files into suitable folders depending on who is in each folder. Plus a folder of files with no one in them.